# Website behavior different when reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm facing the following problem, when I refresh my webpage her behavior is just as expected but when I use reload (just press enter on url input) her behavior becomes weird. When the page is loaded I'm calling a $(document).ready function and inside of it I'm getting an element height. Well in the first case (refresh) the height of the element is just fine, but in the second case (reload) this height is smaller, which causes the problem I'm talking about.

Why is this happen? And how can I prevent this without forcing the webpage to refresh?

Thanks

Comment: Some code would be really helpful.

Comment: Reloading causes data to be sent again (even POST data). Reentering the URL causes the URL to be called and only the URL || In addition it could be a caching thing, as a normal refresh might load the browser cache. Try CTRL+F5

Comment: Yes but the website seems to have a different behavior (when it shouldn't)

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks the same in latest FF

Comment: I tried in chrome and safari

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your browser is caching on reload but when you hit enter on the url it's not loading the site form cache. This is why your page isn't getting the height of the div properly.

I had this problem before and I solved it with this:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function()
        // get the height of elements here
    }, 250);
});
```

Needless to say this solution isn't ideal. If you can try and set the height in css.

Comment: I found the problem and I fixed it based on the following: 1. The document ready event is called after the html document has been loaded and 2. The onload event occurs when all content has been loaded (in this case the images). That's why I the images height where 0 and my div height was smaller. So I just changed The event to onload and it's working perfectly. Your solution tries to do this (although it's a less elegant), with the Timeout you are just waiting for the images to be loaded.